# How much rep can you earn in a day?

Tags: discussion, reputation

How much reputation can you earn in a day? In answering multiple Featured questions you must be able to earn over 200.

Comment: A small amount of searching gives you [this question](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/208/reputation-cap-not-being-enforced), which answers your question handily.

Answer (score 6):

Rep caps out at 200 per day. This does not include accepted answers, *accepting* answers, or bounties.

Comment: It does include, however, downvotes. 195 + upvote → 200 - downvote → 198 + upvote → 200.